# PHP removing a substring from a string

Tags: php, regex

Hey, I need to delete a part of a string (I'm not a :

```
$content = "user=predator1&scode=mau4&athleteid=17007";

$content = "user=predator1&athleteid=17007";
```

I need to delete the "$code=XXXXX" part (the XXXXX part is variable)

I've tried using this:

```
$content = preg_replace("/&scode=[^a-z]*/", "", $content);
```

but doesn't work...

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a simpler/faster method that involves regex but this method is safe (`parse_str` ensures the query string is properly parsed).

```
$content = "user=predator1&scode=mau4&athleteid=17007";

parse_str($content, $vars);

if (isset($vars['code']))
{
 unset($vars['code']);
}

$content = http_build_query($vars);

var_dump($content);
```

Docs for `parse_str`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

You should try this line:

```
 $content = preg_replace("/&scode=[a-zA-Z0-9]*/", "", $content);
```

It says to remove anything which starts with `&scode` which is followed by any number of lowercase letter, uppercase letters, or numbers.

In your original code, you were using `[^a-z]*`. The `^` in your character list said to **not** match on any lowercase letters, so it would stop replacing content as soon as it saw a lowercase letter. Basically, your regex would remove only numbers that started a code, but wouldn't remove anything else in the code if it included a lowercase character.

My regex above is an inclusive list, saying to remove anything that's on the list, so it will remove any alphanumeric character.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but if the last character of the substring is an alphanumeric one like $content = "user=predator1&scode=mau4" (and not the & of another parameter), how can I setup the regular expression to manage this option?

Comment: @Gabriele: I'm not sure what you're asking. The regex in my answer does match that string.

Comment: @Gabriele: Do you mean "what if `scode` is the *first* variable, and therefore *doesn't* have a leading `&`? You can do that with pretty easily. If that's what you mean, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but at the end I've used the John Himmelman version. Is working perfectly without any problem!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `"/&scode=[^a-z]*/"` be more like `"/&scode=[a-zA-Z0-9]*/"`?

Answer (score 0):

This would work without using a regular expression:

```
$pre = "user=predator1&scode=mau4&athleteid=17007";
$exp = explode('&', $pre);
$content = implode('&', array($exp[0], $exp[2]));
```

Comment: Only if there are only three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/code=[a-zA-Z0-9]*/", "code=", $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace("|&scode=[a-zA-Z0-9]+&|", '&', $content);
```