# Remove specific string from a long string using php

Tags: php

How do I remove **{SEP}, date, name, colon(:)** from this `$string` using php ?

```
$string = "{SEP}09-27-2014 19:38 PM alex : hmm..{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 20:04 PM alex : note here..{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 20:05 PM alex : testing{SEP}
{SEP}09-27-2014 20:07 PM alex : 1{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 20:29 PM alex : abc{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 20:30 PM alex : nice..{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 
20:32 PM alex : checking by pressing the save button.{SEP}{SEP}09-27-2014 20:32 PM alex : Ok now check without save button.{SEP}";
```

so that it will be look like this :

```
hmm.. note here..testing 1 abc nice..checking by pressing the save button. Ok now check 
without save button.
```

Comment: please provide full code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455821/php-removing-a-substring-from-a-string

Comment: look on this website for preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace would be a good place to start:

```
echo preg_replace("/\{SEP\}(.+?)\s:\s(.+?)\{SEP\}/m", "$2", $string);
```

Comment: seems not working. It's not remove the specific text like `{SEP}, date, name and colon`.

Comment: It works for me and my output is `hmm..note here..testing1abcnice..checking by pressing the save button.Ok now check without save button.`